# Add single character to string without using update

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, replace

## Problem

I have around five hundred names in a database that end with an abbreviated name, *e.g.*:

```
┌────────────┬───────────┐
│ FNAME      │ LNAME     │
├────────────┼───────────┤
│ Berthe M   │ Bjaaland  │
│ Markus M   │ Nilsen    │
│ Ole T      │ Rasmussen │
└────────────┴───────────┘
```

I would like to use a find and replace to add a full stop after all the single-character names (no Norwegian names consist of single characters, so I know they all are abbreviations). This would be easy if I could run an update query, but I do not have access to that. Is there a way to do this with find and replace or some other workaround?

### *Desired result*

```
┌────────────┬───────────┐
│ FNAME      │ LNAME     │
├────────────┼───────────┤
│ Berthe M.  │ Bjaaland  │
│ Markus M.  │ Nilsen    │
│ Ole T.     │ Rasmussen │
└────────────┴───────────┘
```

### *Further usage*

Once I get this working, the same method would be applied to changing all names with a single letter in the middle, that is with a syntax like ‘* ? *’.

───

## Notes

I am running Access 2007 towards Oracle.

SQL to find names:

```
select KOMMNR, KRETSNR, BOSTNR, PERSNR,
       FORNVN, ETTNVN
  from FOLKETELLINGER_KPERSON_1875
 where FORNVN like "* ?";
```

I found I couldn’t use this syntax to run a filter, as it returned anything ending in a character, rather than anything ending in a space *and* a character. This surprised me, as I have found that many of the dummy characters you can use in `like` queries work well in searches/filters too.

I assume the SQL I would need to run an update, would look something like this:

```
update FOLKETELLINGER_KPERSON_1875
   set FOLKETELLINGER_KPERSON_1875.FORNVN = "* ?."
 where FOLKETELLINGER_KPERSON_1875.FORNVN Like "* ?";
```

I tried copying this syntax to do a single find and replace, but the field was instead changed to ‘* ?.’, not to much surprise.

───

P. S.: I added the sql-update tag, even though I specifically do *not* want to use it; if it should be removed, please let me know in the comments.

P. P. S.: Drawing an ASCII table was surprisingly calming; now I actually want to get back to work …

Comment: Add some more sample data, without single letter, with dot etc. And adjust the result. Any trailing blanks?

Comment: only other way is to read all data, store them somewhere, edit them in any way, delete old data from database and insert new ones. that is the long-winded way of what `update` does way more efficiently

Comment: try this like "% ?"; and also: update FOLKETELLINGER_KPERSON_1875
   set FOLKETELLINGER_KPERSON_1875.FORNVN = FOLKETELLINGER_KPERSON_1875.FORNVN + "."
 where FOLKETELLINGER_KPERSON_1875.FORNVN Like "% ?";

Comment: P.P.P.S. Less calming, but a lot quicker: http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: Add some logic after retrieving your data to fix the data.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by "I do not have access to [running an update query]". Do you actually need to *change* the data in the database? If so, how is it that you can do "find and replace" but not run an update query?

Comment: @Gord Thompson: I can do single actions in the db, but update has been restricted. I suppose find & replace is considered manual enough to allow it.

Comment: @PeterRing I specifically wrote that I do not have access to running update queries, i.e. my user level is not permitted to run update queries towards the server.

Comment: @jarlh What kind of sample data do you mean? I fail to see how variant data would aid the question. As the whole idea is to first select the *relevant* data, then modify it, I do not see how adding examples without this would benefit the question.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Partly what I did when trying out the solution: I created a backup table which I tested the solution on, then ran it on the actual linked table.

Comment: @Carra I do not understand what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to update the data, write a SELECT query to get the desired result.

`IIf()` to distinguish the cases:

```
SELECT FORNVN, [FORNVN] & IIf([FORNVN] Like "* ?",".","") AS FORNVN_Dot
FROM etc.
```

Comment: An excellent solution! After performing your query, all that was left to do, was examine the results (just as desired) and copy-paste them. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set by pattern. Add only one ".".

```
update FOLKETELLINGER_KPERSON_1875
set FOLKETELLINGER_KPERSON_1875.FORNVN = FOLKETELLINGER_KPERSON_1875.FORNVN & "."
where FOLKETELLINGER_KPERSON_1875.FORNVN Like "* ?";
```

Comment: This suggested solution ignores the problem that I cannot run update queries.